# how to copy only unhidden rows from an excel and mail via outlook

Tags: excel, vba

I am not VBA Guru but know a bit. I got stuck in 1 area. Let me describe the scenario below:

I want to send some details to my counterpart using Excel via mail. Some of the data I don't need and I have used some VBA code which actually hides the rows. Now whenever I am using my code to copy the entire page (as HTML format) and send using outlook it actually takes the hidden rows too which I don't want to send.

** Code to Hide Rows which is blank **

```
Sub Example()
    Dim cel As Range, rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("E8:E31")
    For Each cel In rng
       If cel.Value = "" Then
           cel.EntireRow.Hidden = True
       End If
    Next cel 
End Sub
```

---

** Code to send mail **

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
'Working in Office 2000-2010
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

**Untested**, but try changing:

```
rng.Copy
```

to

```
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

This will only copy the non-hidden rows.

Comment: Hi Joe, I tried with your solution but actually its not copying anything and sending out a blank mail (earlier with my code it was sending the entire copied data both hidden-unhidden)

Comment: Hi Joe, I tried with your solution but actually its not copying anything and sending out a blank mail (earlier with my code it was sending the entire copied data both hidden-unhidden)

Comment: It worked for me in a test that I just did (I populated some cells in column `E`, then called `RangeToHTML(Range("1:10"))`.  Are you passing the entire row as the range?  And are you sure that it's the Copy that isn't working?

Comment: Hi Joe, yes I am copying the entire row from beging and now wanted to do the same after I hide some rows using 1st piece of code. e.g. I have no data's on E3, E5, E7 (from E1:E10)...so I would like to send the data over mail showing only rows that contains data (E1,E2,E4,E6,E8,E9,E10)...

Comment: But how are you calling `RangetoHTML`?  Are you passing the row as a range?

Comment: Hi Joe, Yes I am passing the entire sheet rows as row for rng variable

Comment: Hard to figure out the problem, since it works fine for me.  Try `rng.select : rng.copy`; then step through the code and see if the row is actually being selected and copied.

Comment: Hi Joe, Can you provide me your email id pls? i will send you the excel report for which i want to run the code and send the same via outlook email using above code.

Comment: Well, no :)  But if you want to post it via Dropbox or something similar, I'll take a look.

Comment: Well, thanks Joe for your help so far. Your piece of code havent worked for me but still thanks for trying to help me out. I will post it further to see if anyone has any otherr solution.